# vertical and horizontal line in a matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices, rules

I want to create a `bmatrix` on the right

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}[c|c]
        _B[T]_B & * \\
        0 & _{\overline{B'}} [\overline{T}] _{\overline{B'}}
\end{bmatrix}   
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

gives me

[image]

How do I make verticle line work? and how do I insert horizontal line?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99238/compact-block-matrix?rq=1

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230500/15925

Answer (score 18):

You could use an `array` instead; in this way, the standard `|` for the vertical rule and `\hline` (for the horizontal rule) will give you the desired result. The brackets can be obtained using `\mleft`, `\mright` from the [`mleftright`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) package:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\mleft[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \epsilon' [T|_A]\epsilon & \ast \\
  \hline
  0 & _{\overline{B}'} [\overline{T}] _{\overline{B}\vphantom{\overline{B}'}}
\end{array}
\mright]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a possibility, but doesn't answer the question of how to get a horizontal line in `bmatrix`. I changed my `bmatrix` to `array` and it took the `\hline`, but then the `array` broke the `align` environment.  When I searched for how to use `array` inside `align`, everything I found said to use `bmatrix`. Any ideas how to get a horizontal line inside a matrix inside an `align` environment? (OMG, LaTeX is frustrating. I can't believe we have to put up with all this just to write a document.)

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution [here](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/amsmath-matrix/). The idea is paste the following in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
```

With that, any `matrix` environment has as optional argument the array alignment (as you suggested), and you could use also `\hline`. So for example:

```
\begin{bmatrix}[c|c]
    _B[T]_B & * \\ \hline
    0 & _{\overline{B'}} [\overline{T}] _{\overline{B'}}
\end{bmatrix}
```

will behave as you want.

Answer (score 8):

I used an array inside of a `bmatrix`, because one of my editing environments didn't parse the large square brackets correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{array}{c|c}
  \epsilon' [T|_A]\epsilon & \ast \\
  \hline
  0 & _{\overline{B}'} [\overline{T}]
  _{\overline{B}\vphantom{\overline{B}'}}
    \end{array}
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity ... why within a matrix and not within \left[ and \right]?