# Block matrix with partial vertical line

Tags: spacing, matrices, nicematrix

I would like to create a partial block matrix, with two blocks on the bottom row, separated by a vertical line between them, and separated from the rest of the matrix by a horizontal line.

My first attempt captured the idea, but the alignment was lacking

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}
\newcommand{\bigid}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries I}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \begin{matrix}
        1 & x_0 & x_0^2  & \dots & x_0^n \\
          &     & \vdots &       & \\
        1 & x_m & x_m^2  & \dots & x_m^n \\
      \end{matrix} \\
      \hline
      \begin{array}{c c | c c c}
        \bigzero & & & \bigid_{n-m} &
      \end{array}
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Original matrix]

*Ideally, I would like a little more space between the horizontal line and the rows. Furthermore, the `0` should be centred between the first two columns, while the `I` should be centred between the last three columns.*

I was able to obtain a much better spacing using the `nicematrix` package, however I have no idea how to produce the vertical line, which *should join with the horizontal line but not spread into the first three rows.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}
\newcommand{\bigid}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries I}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pNiceArray}{CCCCC}
      1 & x_0 & x_0^2  & \cdots & x_0^n \\
        &     & \Vdots &       & \\
      1 & x_m & x_m^2  & \cdots & x_m^n \\
      \hline
      \Block{2-2}{\bigzero} & & \Block{2-3}{\bigid_{n-m}} &  \\
      & & & &
    \end{pNiceArray}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a typo in your code: you wrote `{\bigid_{n-m})` instead of `{\bigid_{n-m}}`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99238/compact-block-matrix/

Comment: @ABlueChameleon I read that question while doing my due diligence, but not only it is not immediately clear how to adapt the answer to this particular case, it also seems a lot more convoluted than using `nicematrix`.

Comment: @A.P. I didn't mean to say that I thought this was a duplicate or anything, but rather that if someone was looking for ways to typeset block matrices, there were additional options over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw the rule you want with a TikZ instruction:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}
\newcommand{\bigid}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries I}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
      1 & x_0 & x_0^2  & \Cdots & x_0^n \\
        &     & \Vdots &       & \\
      1 & x_m & x_m^2  & \Cdots & x_m^n \\
      \hline
      \Block{2-2}{\bigzero} & & \Block{2-3}{\bigid_{n-m}} &  \\
      & & & &
      \CodeAfter
      \tikz \draw (4-|3) -- (6-|3) ;
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the first code]

---

With recent versions of `nicematrix`, you can merely use the key `borders` of the command `\Block`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}
\newcommand{\bigid}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries I}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pNiceArray}{ccccc}
      1 & x_0 & x_0^2  & \cdots & x_0^n \\
        &     & \Vdots &       & \\
      1 & x_m & x_m^2  & \cdots & x_m^n \\
      \Hline
      \Block[borders=right]{2-2}{\bigzero} & & \Block{2-3}{\bigid_{n-m}} &  \\
      & & & &
    \end{pNiceArray}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: I miss similar example in package documentation. With some explanation, how vertical line is drawn. Also, is there a way to draw`\hline˙ that it will not touch delimiter parenthesis (use option `margin move vertical lines between block)?

Comment: @Zarko: You are right. It's not possible to understand how this answer works because the documentation of `nicematrix` is incomplete. I will complete that documentation soon.  In a few words, the recent versions of `nicematrix` create new nodes, a node for each row and a node for each column corresponding to the position of the (potential) rules in the array.

Comment: @Zarko: It's not possible to change the horizontal rule created by `\hline`. The command `\hline` has not been modified by `nicematrix`. However, it's possible to use `\cmidrule` of `booktabs` to have an horizontal rule a bit shorter.

Comment: Thank you for explanation in the first comment. Solution proposed in second comments works (fine), but to my opinion is to rude.  Use simple `\hline` in conjunction with `margin` option, if they will work properly, seems to be more consistent with existed solution (which not use new nodes for rows and columns). Anyway, +1 for answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get this to run (I copied your code as-is). I get two errors: _Undefined control sequence. \CodeAfter_ and _Package pgf Error: No shape named col-3 is known_ (plus similar ones for `row-4` and `row-6`. I tried upgrading `nicematrix` to the latest available revision (54758 according to my `tllocalmgr`), to no avail.

Comment: @A.P.: I think you have not the latest version of `nicematrix`. The number 54758 is not the number of version of `nicematrix` (it's an internal number of TeXLive). In order to have the version of `nicematrix`, you can look in the `aux` file generated by the (aborted) compilation. The latest version of `nicematrix` is 3.15 (2020-04-06).

Comment: As it turns out, while I had installed the newest version of `nicematrix`, I had failed to run `texhash` properly. Now it seems to compile properly (aside from a "pdflatex is too old" warning"). Thank you for a nice and elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use two instructions `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}
\newcommand{\bigid}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries I}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
      1 & x_0 & x_0^2  & \Cdots & x_0^n \\
        &     & \Vdots &       & \\
      1 & x_m & x_m^2  & \Cdots & x_m^n \\
      \hline
      \Block{2-2}{\bigzero} & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{} & \Block{2-3}{\bigid_{n-m}} &  \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{} & & &
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: While I like this solution because it is in a sense simpler in not requiring `tikz`, I prefer the more centred alignment of the vertical bar in your other answer.